# In-app rating Feature in iOS and about it limits

Tags: ios, skstorereviewcontroller

Apple is limiting the review prompt (Rate This App) to 3 times a year and it can be turned off in the user's settings.

I want to ask 3 things related to that:

1. Is it possible to show the in-app rating popup more than 3 times?
2. What will happen when a user taps on the prompt’s submit button? Will it dismiss the popup? Will it redirect to the App Store?
3. Is there a way to detect when a user has disabled the Rating Prompt from their device settings?

Answer (score 9):

1. You can't show it more than 3 times per year. This is a limit imposed on the operating system level.
2. All user interaction happens directly in the dialog
3. As far as I know you can't detect that, and you don't need to. You just call `requestReview()` on `SKStoreReviewController` when you think it is appropriate, but never directly due to a user action (e.g. a "Rate Me" button). However, you can manually request a review by opening the URL `https://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXXX?action=write-review` as explained in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/requesting_app_store_reviews).

I think you also should have a look at the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/ratings-and-reviews/) to get a sense for how to use the review dialog.

Comment: for Point 3: We can add if it 1,2,3 request then open the rating popup else open URL with itunes link.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't increase the limit of this popup. As it's already decided by apple.
2. So the benefit of this dialogue is that you don't need to go to app store to submit your ratings. That is why it increase the ratings of your applications. It will not redirect you anywhere the rating directly submitted from here on AppStore.
3. No user or developer both can't detect this popup. So it's not possible for user to disable this.

For more information you can read this blog -: https://nehajainjvwu.medium.com/in-app-rating-popup-apple-rating-popup-1e445f97803d

Answer (score -1):

How said in documentation, 2024 actual https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requesting_app_store_reviews#4312600

To enable a person to initiate a review as a result of an action in the UI, the sample code uses a deep link to the App Store page for the app with the query parameter action=write-review appended to the URL:

Functions that helps you in code (where the APP_ID is your app id from App Store Connect):

```
    func rateApp() {
        openExternalLink(
            "https://apps.apple.com/app/id\(APP_ID)?action=write-review"
        )
    }

    func openExternalLink(_ urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(
                url,
                options: [:],
                completionHandler: nil
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: This makes no attempt to answer the question as asked.

Comment: @HangarRash sure, sorry, i just not get in touch with a question about that this feature are limited in-app - he meant that he can't show dialog for user about rate-up (where stars appears to rate and then navigate user to app-store?) - hmm...